# How do I select an Index in an array within the MFMailViewController setToRecipients?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am using the MFMailViewController in Xcode and I have this line setting the recipients.

```
[mailComposer setToRecipients:emailAddresses];
```

I need to set the Recipient to a certain index within the NSArray but I cannot figure out how to do this.

If you still don't understand what I mean I need the email address to be one person or another depending on something that a user has input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do something like this:

```
if (useBobsEmail)
{
    [mailComposer setToRecipients:@[@"bob@somewhere.com"]];
}
else
{
    [mailComposer setToRecipients:@[@"joe@somewhereelse.com]];
}
```

The `@[]` notation, if you're unaware, can be used in place of `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:]`.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was exactly what I needed. I did not now that @[] acted like an NSArray. I was trying to use a string and it just wasn't working. Thanks again.